# Simple Game Inventory

Tags: python, inventory

so I am trying again to post this in a correct manner, but I am struggling with adding items to an inventory for a very simple text based game for a class project. The output should be as folllows:

```
You are in (room)
Inventory: []
You see a (item)
What do you wish to do?
```

In my game, the player will type a command like `get Sword` to pick up an item. If that item isnt in the room they are in it should output `You cant get that item here`. Once the player gets the item in the room, it should be added into the inventory and removed from the room so that the input reads:

```
You are in (room)
Inventory: [Sword]
You dont see anything useful
What do you wish to do?
```

I am having trouble getting the inventory to update and then the item no longer being in the room. When I am in the room I try to get the item and it says `You cant get that item here` even if the item is in the room.
Below is a simplified version of my code, any help is appreciated greatly.

```
# A dictionary for the simplified text game that links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
        'Entrance Hall': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Gallery', 'West': 'Library', 'item': 'None'},
        'Library': {'East': 'Entrance Hall', 'item': 'Book'},
        'Gallery': {'West': 'Entrance Hall', 'item': 'Sword'}
    }

instructions = 'To move type: go North, go East, go West, go South' \
               'to get items type get Item, ex: get Sword\n '

directions = ['go North', 'go South', 'go East', 'go West']
pick_up_items = ['get Ale', 'get Book', 'get Armor', 'get Sword', 'Necromancer', 'get Knife', 'get Candle']

print(instructions)
current_room = 'Entrance Hall'
item_in_room = 'None'
inventory = []

while True:
    print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_room))
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    if item_in_room == 'None':
        print("You don't see anything useful")
    else:
        print('You see a', item_in_room)

    # gets the users input
    command = input('\nWhat do you wish to do? ')  # this controls the movement
    if command in directions:
        command = command.split()[1]
        if command in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
            item_in_room = rooms[current_room]['item']
        else:
            # if the player inputs a bad movement
            print('You cant go that way!')
    # Checks to see if the player types a 'get' command and adds the item in the room to the players inventory.
    if command in pick_up_items:
        command = command.split()[1]
        if command in rooms[current_room].keys():
            inventory.append(current_room['item'])
        else:
            # if the player inputs a item not in the room
            print('You cant get that item here!')
```

Comment: I could be wrong but looks like in line 6, `item_in_room = None` is going to start your loop with `None` every time.

Comment: Yeah but that changes inside the loop when the player goes to a different room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, your check for items is wrong.
Your item is in the `rooms[current_room]['item']` not `rooms[current_room].keys()`

```py
if command == rooms[current_room]['item']:
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item']) #another error i found out
    rooms[current_room]['item'] = 'None' #make sure that you check that command isn't None or it will be added as an Item
# other stuff
```

If you are planning on placing multiple items in a room, I suggest that you convert the `item` key in all dictionaries to a list to make the checking easier. Also, `go item` will also pass your direction check and raise an error.

Comment: Yeah I havent yet added in the Invalid Input that will check to make sure its one or the other. I had it added but it was causing an issue so I took it out until I could get the inventory system sorted first then I would make sure that the inputs were checked

But how would I make sure it removes the book from the room after it gets added to the Inventory?

Comment: Edited my answer