# Items won't increment when called upon

Tags: python

```
def guardroom():  # start of Guard Room the second room
    print('You crash into some armor: put it on?')
    piece = input()  # input to add item to player
    current_room = rooms['Guard Room']  # defines current room
    items = 0
    if items == 0 and (piece == 'pick up'):  # suppose to make it so you can only pick the item up once
        print('You gained a worn out robe')  #
        items += 1                           #
        return items                         #
    elif items != 0 and (piece == 'pick up'):  #
        print('You currently adorn your robe')  #
    print('Enter a direction:')
    direction = input()
    if direction == 'exit':
        print('The game is over')
        stop()
        pass
    elif direction in current_room and direction == 'North':  # moves you to the great hall
        print('You moved to the Keep')
        great_hall()
    elif direction in current_room and direction == 'East':  # moves you to the Cellar again
        print('You find yourself in the Cell')
        cell()
    elif direction not in current_room:
        print('You cannot go that way!')
        return guardroom()
```

I need to get it so that items gets increased and when you try and pick the piece up again you wont be able to. I tried defining `inventory()` to increment items but it wont return the incremented item. And with this code by returning items it just starts the code back over and then my code gets weird and breaks.

Comment: I guess you want `if current_room and (piece == 'pick up'):` instead of `if current_room and piece == 'pick up':`.

Comment: You should properly indent your code and show error message if you have any,otherwise show more code so we can run it. See [mre]

Comment: @JoãoVictor Those statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get it so that items gets increased and when you try and pick the piece up again you wont be able to.

Every time that you call your function you are setting `items = 0` and then immediately asking if it equals 0. Which it will. You need somewhere else to store your item count. A functional way of accomplishing this would be to declare your `items` variable globally then pass it in to your function as a parameter like this:

```
def guardroom(currentItemCount):
  if currentItemCount == 0:
    currentItemCount += 1;
  elif currentItemCount > 0:
    print('You currently adorn your robe') 
  return currentItemCount;

items = 0
items = guardroom(items)
```

This is just what seems like would be easier for you though. A better solution for what you are trying to accomplish would be like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67182645/simple-game-inventory?rq=1) and of course there are even better approaches that would be more advanced.

> And with this code by returning items it just starts the code back over and then my code gets weird and breaks.

That's not a question really and one possible reason for this is outside of the scope of your original question. But since you provided the broken code I'll try to help you out.

```
def guardroom():
  return guardroom();
```

This is what is called a recursive function. As I have defined it here, if I call this function, it will never stop until it reaches a limit of system resources. To understand why I highly suggest you research recursive functions, how to do them properly, and what a stack overflow is(it's not just a forum for getting answers to coding questions). These may be more advanced topics than you are looking, or are ready, for. But to make a long story short:

It is generally a bad idea to do your navigation logic this way since the user could potentially make the recursive call indefinitely which will crash your application eventually. Instead you might try a loop like this:

```
cmd = input();
while cmd != "exit":
  // process and gather results from command
  // possibly do something with gathered results
  cmd = input(); // solicit next command.
```

In case you are not sure where you caused this recursive function call it was here:

```
elif direction not in current_room:
    print('You cannot go that way!')
    return guardroom()
```